# SQL Server : Partitioning rows while importing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, dbeaver

I have this thousands of rows approximately each file has 250000 rows, and there are 3 files that almost a million rows. I need to import them into my table. The problem is, the process is so slow and there're chances the internet goes down so I need to delete the half rows already imported and re-import them back. Whole rows. The data is in format of `xslx` or `csv`. I'm doing this activity with `DBeaver` feature to import the data. I'm thinking if I could partition the rows into several partitions of rows.

1. Is there any way to do it?
2. Can it be done by line of code or else? Or do I have to partition the rows manually on excel?

Comment: You could use a language such as Java (or .NET, Python, PHP, etc.) to read say 10K rows at a time, and then output a new flat file based on that.  Then, read each flat file 10K records at a time.

Comment: You can try with SSIS package alos.SSIS faster import compare with sql server import/export wizard